# Rewrite rule: change a portion of text in URL to another

Tags: wordpress, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change the url of my wordpress, I have read that I can make that with rewrite rule but it does not work me unfortunately. Here are the details:

I have a wordpress theme, which got me that kind of URL:

```
www.my-theme.pl/portfolio_category/red-flower/
www.my-theme.pl/portfolio_category/blue-flower/
www.my-theme.pl/portfolio_category/black-trees/
www.my-theme.pl/portfolio_category/white-roses/
```

I want to rewrite the URL via .htaccess to receive:
www.my-theme.pl/gardens/red-flower/

As you see, I just want to replace /portfolio_category/ with /gardens/ text in the URL since after that are different post names but the /portfolio_category/ always stays the same.

I entered this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/portfolio_category/$ /gardens/$ [NC]
```

And it does not work unfortunately. Can you clarify how to use properly ? 
Below is my entire .htaccess code:

```
Options -Indexes
AuthType Basic
AuthName "password"
AuthUserFile /home/*******************/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/portfolio_category/$ /gardens/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The ******* are replaced with working path to my htpasswd.
It is my first time to make any rewrite changes and I am not familiar with it. I think I have read the tutorials correctly but the change still does not work.

Best regards from Poland,
Jacek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, your rewrite rule is reversed and you are not including the following directory. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/gardens/(.*)$ /portfolio_category/$1 [NC]
```

This changes /gardens/ to /portfolio_category/. The (.*)$ collects everything to the end of the URL, then the $1 adds it at the end of the new one.

Comment: No, I want to change *existing* /portfolio_category/ into new /gardens/ text in my URL. No the other way around.

Comment: A rewrite rule rewrites the incoming URL to a new URL. Your rule will not rewrite http://example.com/gardens/.. because the left side of your rewrite rule does not match. Is that what you want?

Comment: Im sorry Sir but since I do not understand the rewrite module and its syntax I probably have trouble to understand your answer. I will try to be as simple as i can:

I have right now: www.my-theme.pl/portfolio_category/XXXXXX
where xxx is the random post names

I *want* to have: www.my-theme.pl/gardens/XXXXXX


If you tell me that I want to change gardens into portfolio_category i feel confused because I want to: change portfolio into gardens.

Comment: The rewrite rule I wrote says: If the incoming URL is http://example.com/gardens/something/, then rewrite it as http://example.com/portfolio_category/something/. In this case, the second URL is the one your web server will understand. If the reverse it the case, then you would need to reverse them.

Comment: In either case, you need to also copy the directory after.

Comment: Ok, I think im getting it - so I need to specify also the names of the different posts to make it work ? You can not just swap the text in URL and leave the rest alone to work ?

Comment: A rewrite will automatically copy over a query string (the ? and everything after), but will not automatically copy the rest of the URL. This is because you might want to rewrite and NOT copy the rest of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mr bodye, I think my problem is solved and I simply need to code the change into my theme to get different URL by the theme engine so the URL is proper from the start without need of the rewrite.